# How to send C++ winsock Get Request?

Tags: c++, http-headers, winsock, bittorrent

I'm trying to write a bittorrent client and I need to work out how to send a HTTP GET request to the tracker with some specific parameters which can be found here: http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html#anchor18

I think I just about understand how to open a socket but how would I send a GET request in C++ on windows?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you really want to issue HTTP requests, using a socket is probably too raw. Unless your are doing this as an exercise, you should aim for a HTTP library, like [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) which will take care of all the HTTP complex stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your TCP socket is open, you need to issue a HTTP GET request.
This is actually very simple: you just need to send through the socket a series of text lines,  as described for example here:

http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#sample

You ends your request with an empty line.

Then you wait for the server to reply, and you cross your fingers...

In your case, all the parameters will be on the GET line with parameters after the URL:

GET url?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

Comment: This would work for any trivial program, but if the OP wants to code a real bittorrent client, he will have to handle a lot of different HTTP return codes, compression, encoding, url-encoding, and so on. He better off use a library that already does that well.